# Vertically center align an image in it's parent

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML/CSS:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_Q75eDHE.jpeg" alt="img" />
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekpzwkkd/)**

Is there any way I can vertically center the image in it's container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_Q75eDHE.jpeg" alt="img" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your image is bigger than your container... Is it normal ?

I suggest you to use a background image in this case... (with background-position: center and background-size:cover)

Answer (score 0):

Change css

CSS

```
div.horizontal {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

div.vertical {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}




.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="horizontal container div1">
    <div class="vertical">
        <img src="http://www.wallpapereast.com/static/images/HD-Wallpapers1_Q75eDHE.jpeg" alt="img" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo Link http://jsfiddle.net/LWrSD/430/